# Angular js set form to Pristine false

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I've a html form and I'm adding validation to each input within the from using angular js.

But I don't want to show the validation error initially when the html loads, until the user makes some changes in the form.

So I've validation like:

```
<form name="addApplicationForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="applicationData.application_name" required>
    <div ng-show="addApplicationForm.name.$invalid && !addApplicationForm.name.$pristine">
      <span class="error" ng-show="addApplicationForm.name.$error.required">Please enter application name.</span>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And this form works as I expected. Now if the user directly clicks the submit button without making any change in the input, the $pristine state is still true and the error does now shows. But here I want to show the validation error to the user.

That's why on submit, I want to set the $pristine state of the form to false, but I'm not seeing a method for it.

I also tried with $dirty instead of $pristine like:

```
<form name="addApplicationForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="applicationData.application_name" required>
    <div ng-show="addApplicationForm.name.$invalid && !addApplicationForm.name.$dirty">
      <span class="error" ng-show="addApplicationForm.name.$error.required">Please enter application name.</span>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And on submit I just call the setDirty method to make the form dirty and thus it shows the error on the submit button click.

But here the problem is, I also have a reset button in the form. Once clicked, I want to clear all the fields of the form and then I need to make the dirty flag of the form to false but I don't have any such option. But for this case if I use $pristine I've $setPristine().

So in this case whatever I use $dirty or $pristine, I've one issue here.

Please tell me what could be the solution.

Comment: if the answer is not enough, please provide minimal working snippet with your submit and reset button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$pristine and $dirty should work together. Using `$setPristine` will set the `$pristine` property **of the form** to true and `$dirty` to false. `$setDirty` will do the contrary.

It seems that your issue is related to the fact that you are testing the `$pristine` and `$dirty` properties of a field of your form (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). Doing `$setPristine` on your form controller also propagates to every fields of the form, while `$setDirty` does not.

You can have a look at the source code of angular, where the property are set (#setPristine and #setDirty), this code portion is explicit and easy to read : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js

Comment: Thank you, it works. Actually I was not aware that $setDirty makes the form dirty not the input fields and if I use setPristine it makes the form dirty as false.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, you don't need to set your `form` to anything.

You just have to change your check to:

```
<div ng-show="addApplicationForm.name.$invalid && addApplicationForm.name.$dirty">
```

I'd recommend you to use [**this**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) directive.

Also to check this [**tutorial**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages).